# Tablelayout two columns same width

Tags: android, tablelayout

How to accomplish the following:

- A tablelayout with two columns (textviews)
- Both columns are 50% width
- The text on in the columns (textviews) can be long, but should not be cut/clipped off at the edge, but rather the sentence should break nicely at the column border
- I would also like 10dp margin around the table

I have been trying this myself, but I get into some problems where the text is cut off or the column exceeds 50% of the width.

To illustrate here is a sketch of what I would want (the borders are just for illustration): [link](http://oi42.tinypic.com/9zm15i.jpg)

Comment: So that we can give you a proper answer you will need to provide us with the solutions that you have tried. Don't post questions expecting we do all the work for you ;) you can play with the weight value of your layout. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#weight

Comment: http://androidadvice.blogspot.pt/2010/10/tablelayout-columns-equal-width.html

Comment: Thank you all! I figured it out using Jeffrey Klardie's link and then this link http://androidadvice.blogspot.nl/2010/10/tablelayout-columns-equal-width.html.